# SQL Joins using ParentType and Parent Tables

Tags: sql, join

First question - here goes..

Writing what was a fairly simple Select statement.  I'm joining 8 other tables to get the required data - at least 6 of these tables need to be joined through a ParentType table.

My PPMTask table has amongst other data a 'ParentTypeID' (Pkey for tbParentType) and a 'ParentID' (Pkey for another table depending what ParentType states).

tbPPMTask

```
  Name       ParentTypeID       ParentID
  Item 1       15                 234
  Item 2       15                 235
  Item 3       20                 8756
  Item 4       25                 75344
  Item 5       35                 23
```

tbParentType (below) contains ParentID, ParentType,..  The ParentType text depicts what the 'other' table I join up that contains the ParentID (which is actually the primary key for that table)

tbParentType

```
ParentID     ParentType
   1           Address
   15          Site
   20          Building
   25          Floor
   35          Room
   40          Asset
```

I then need to use the 'ParentType' description above to choose which table to link the 'ParentID' key from the Base table.  Two examples of these tables are below.

tbSite

```
SiteID      SiteName
 233         Site 2b
 234         Site 2c
 235         Site 3a
```

tbBuilding

```
Building ID      Building Name
  8756             Low Building
  8757             High Building
```

I want to write some SQL that will display PPMTask.Name, ParentType.ParentType, Entity - where 'Entity' is either Site.SiteName or Building.BuildingName and so on for the other 4 tables.

So far I've tried adding clauses into my Select line and also my Join line, but I'm getting no where - in fact I seem to be confusing myself more.  Some of my code below:

```
  from tbPPMTask t
  join tbParentType pt on t.ParentTypeID = pt.ParentID
  join (tbSite s on t.ParentID = s.SiteID and t.ParentTypeID = 15
  or tbBuilding b on t.ParentID = b.BuildingName and t.ParentTypeID = 20) as Entity
```

And another example of code thats not working:

```
select t.*
, pt.*
, (select s.SiteName where t.ParentTypeID = 15
or
b.BuildingName where t.ParentTypeID = 20 
 ) as Entity
from tbPPMTask t
join tbParentType pt on t.ParentTypeID = pt.ParentID
join tbSite s on t.ParentID = s.SiteID
join tbBuilding b on t.ParentID = b.BuildingName
```

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: not clear? show your table structure and query

Comment: Can you post your question clearer? Post tables and table fields and the query you have tried so far. Also post some sample data and the expected output

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bit strange design but I decided to give it a shot, I hope I understood correctly.

[Here is a sample in sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/180bb7/4/0)

and the code to illustrate the approach used

```
select 
  b.*
  ,case pt.description
    when 'tbType1' then t1.someData1
    when 'tbType2' then t2.someData2
    when 'tbType3' then t3.someData3
    end
  as someData
  ,t1.*
  ,t2.*
  ,t3.*
from 
  tbBase b
  inner join tbParentType pt on b.parentTypeId = pt.parentTypeId
  left join tbType1 t1 on b.parentId = t1.id and pt.description = 'tbType1'
  left join tbType2 t2 on b.parentId = t2.id and pt.description = 'tbType2'
  left join tbType3 t3 on b.parentId = t3.id and pt.description = 'tbType3'
```

**EDIT**
Just saw your added your schema and sample data. Below is the code for your example

```
select 
  t.*
  ,case pt.ParentType
    when 'Site' then s.SiteName
    when 'Building' then b.[building Name]
    -- etc for other types
    end
  as someDescription
from tbPPMTask t
inner join tbParentType pt on t.ParentTypeID = pt.ParentID
left join tbSite s on t.ParentID = s.SiteID and pt.ParentType = 'Site'
left join tbBuilding b on t.ParentID = b.[Building ID] and pt.ParentType = 'Building'
-- etc for other types
```

Comment: This one worked and I've adapted it to fit. I will adapt it further to utilise the primary keys, rather than the text on the ParentType table, to minimise typos, etc..  Also the example you posted on sqlFiddle proved to be useful, I will try to use this in the future. I will ''Vote Up'' when I gain the required reputation points.

Comment: @KrisGlodek, glad to hear that it solved your problem. I would advise against referencing records by IDs in production code. In many cases IDs are auto-generated and potentially could change if the data is migrated or re-created.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark ... if you expect answers and/or effective assistance, you really need to be able to respond to requests for more information.

```
SELECT BaseTable.*, ChildTableA.*, ChildTableB.*
FROM 
    BaseTable 
     INNER JOIN 
    tbParentType ON 
        BaseTable.ParentTypeID = tbParentType.ParentTypeID
     LEFT JOIN 
    ChildTableA ON 
        tbParentType.ParentID = ChildTableA.ParentID AND
        tbParentType.ParentType = 'ChildTableA'
     LEFT JOIN 
    ChildTableB ON 
        tbParentType.ParentID = ChildTableB.ParentID AND
        tbParentType.ParentType = 'ChildTableB'
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the advice here and above.  I've edited my original question, but was not quick enough to do it before your answer.  I will go and try to translate it to my data.  Thanks again